# How can I copy all metadata, including color profiles, from one jpg to another?

Tags: metadata, color-management, exiftool

I tried `exiftool -tagsFromFile` but it seems to skip color profile exif.

Answer (score 3):

Below is a note from EXIFTools documentation -

"1) Some tags (generally tags which may affect the appearance of the image) are considered "unsafe" to write, and are only copied if specified explicitly (ie. no wildcards). See the tag name documentation for more details about "unsafe" tags."

Also, see question 9b on this page: http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/faq.html

In short, you may have to be explicit in your statement.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trials and errors, I managed to do what you're asking by using the ExifToolGUI (http://u88.n24.queensu.ca/~bogdan/). I tried before with the command line ExifTool, but I just couldn't get the right parameters.

With the ExifToolGUI, you select the source image, go to the menu [Export/Import]-->[Copy metadata into JPG or TIF files...], select the destination image, check all checkboxes for the metadata you want to copy in the next dialog, et voila.

I had an image scanned from an EPSON scanner with an EPSON ICC profile which I wanted to copy on another image and it worked perfect.